# Is $\left( \begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&-a\\ \end{array} \right)$ similar to $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&-1 \\ 1&0\\ \end{array}\right)$ if $a^2+bc=-1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

My question is regarding [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/85423/62169).

The argument goes:

> Given a matrix $A=\left( \begin{array}{cc} a&b \\ c&-a\\ \end{array} \right)$ with $a^2 +bc =-1$ we can assume, without loss of generality, that $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&-1 \\ 1&0\\ \end{array} \right)$.

I took this to mean $A$ is equivalent to $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&-1 \\ 1&0\\ \end{array} \right)$ after some change of basis, i.e. they are similar matrices. However, I'm having trouble finding the explicit change of basis.

I would like to know why we can assume $A = \left( \begin{array}{cc} 0&-1 \\ 1&0\\ \end{array} \right)$ and if this is intuitively obvious, why?

Comment: Note that $a^2+bc=-1$ is equivalent to $\det A = 1$.

Comment: To add to @ZainPatel , observe that the trace of $A$ is $0$.

Comment: @ZainPatel, I don't see how this helps. Are you quoting a result that all matrices with the same determinant are similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Low-tech answer: By explicit computation (using $a^2+bc=-1$), $A^2=-I$. Since $-1$ has no square in $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ has no eigenvalues over $\mathbb{R}$.  So given any nonzero vector $v$, $Av$ is linearly independent from $v$.  Fix any such $v$ and consider the basis $\{v,Av\}$.  Since $A(Av)=-v$, the matrix of $A$ with respect to this basis is $\begin{pmatrix}0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

High-tech answer: The trace of $A$ is $0$, and the determinant of $A$ is $-1$.  The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is thus $$x^2-tr(A)x+\det(A)=x^2+1.$$  Since the characteristic polynomial is squarefree, there is only one possible rational canonical form (over $\mathbb{R}$) for matrices with this characteristic polynomial.  Thus any two such matrices are similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My definition of similar matrices was that they are conjugate. So I'll need to refresh myself of the fact that matrices with the same eigenvalues are similar.

Comment: I have condensed my original answer into a briefer more high-tech version, and added a new much more elementary answer.